# Display data from multidimensional array

Tags: php

How do I display the individual values from this array?

for instance: X = 8.6; Y = 43; F = more stuff?

```
$MEGA['Stuff'] = [
  8.6,
  43,
  'more stuff'
];
```

Comment: `list($x,$y,$f) = $MEGA['Stuff']; echo 'X='.$x; echo 'Y='.$y; echo 'F='.$f;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Object Manipulator answer, above, in case you cannot manipulate the original array, you could use the `array_combine` function to set the keys to the array, thus reducing the need of iterating over it twice.

```
$keys = ["X", "Y", "F"];
$MEGA["Stuff"] = array_combine($keys, $MEGA["Stuff"]);
```

Now the `$MEGA["Stuff"]` array is in the form, Object Manipulator has it, and you can manipulate it at your liking

Answer (score 0):

You could make it an associative array with key-value pair.

```
$MEGA['Stuff'] = [
  'X' => 8.6,
  'Y' => 43,
  'F' => 'more stuff'
];

foreach ($MEGA['Stuff'] as $k => $v) {
    echo $k . ' : '. $v;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose k,y and f is fix therefor use can use following code.
you have 3 characters k,y,f right

arrays count is 3

now you can make code like this

```
$char=array('k','y','f');
```

get count of $MEGA['Stuff'];

```
$count=count($MEGA['Stuff']);
```

Now we are using for loop.

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
     echo $char[$i].' = '.$MEGA['Stuff'][$i];echo '<br/>';
}
```

You can use this code for display value from array.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use echo to display the data:

```
echo $MEGA['stuff'][0])
echo $MEGA['stuff'][1])
echo $MEGA['stuff'][2])
```

Comment: This was the simpler answer and it worked like a charm. thanks!